# Powershell script. How to trigger input field change event in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, powershell

I am trying to change an input field in the following website and trigger the relative event. (the "Target Output Frequency :" field in the "Spur Table" tab)
https://www.analog.com/designtools/en/simdds/?part=AD9914&fin=3.5G&mult=1&ftw=24C118DE&rso=111111&harmonicDB=-40&useFilters=1&fType=0&fTop=0&fOrder=6&fc=900M

I have used the following code. I succeeded clicking on the tab and changing input field value but I couldn't trigger its associated event. Could you please guide me how to do that?

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible= $true
$ie.Navigate("https://www.analog.com/designtools/en/simdds/?part=AD9914&fin=3.5G&mult=1&ftw=24C118DE&rso=111111&harmonicDB=-40&useFilters=1&fType=0&fTop=0&fOrder=6&fc=900M")

while ($ie.Busy -eq $true){Start-Sleep -seconds 1;}  

$spurtableBTN = $ie.Document.body.getElementsByClassName("dds-table-tab") | Where { $_.id -eq 'spur_table_tab' }

$spurtableBTN.click()

$inputFreq = $ie.Document.body.getElementsByClassName("ember-text-field") | Where { $_.id -eq 'target_output_freq_textbox' }
$inputFreq.value = "600M"
$inputFreq.onblur()
```

Comment: What happens if you do `$inputFreq.onchange()`. This event fires the moment when the value of the element is changed. Read about [HTML Events](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp)

Comment: @Theo : It doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this to this website, the way your are trying to, becasue they are preventing it.

If you step further into the source code on the page, they are trapping all element events your are trying to target, by using several function(s).

Basically any interactive event will cause the update after the change in that Frequency field. Since you cannot call or trigger those methods in their function(s) from PowerShell, the that will be a catch22.

You may need to resort of leveraging something like …
[Using Selenium WebDriver with PowerShell](http://ps1coding.blogspot.com/2015/07/using-selenium-webdriver-with.html)

To get the level of automation you are after.

Answer (score 0):

This took a bit of digging through blog posts and looking at the properties and methods of objects exposed through main IE handle, $ie in the example.  I also looked at the code using F12 in Internet Explorer and the body property of Document object.
For the site i was working on, I found the following section of code.  I needed the site to display as many items as possible in the list, which defaulted to 100.

```
<select name="DisplayCount" id="DisplayCount" onchange="javascript:fetchList(1, this)">
    <option value="100" selected="">100
    <option value="500">500
    <option value="1000">1000
</option>
```

As the requester pointed out, you can change the value, but it doesn't make the call to perform the update.

I found a method called FireEvent and after a couple tries, figured out to pass the event name, "onchange".
The first step is to change the value, then force the onchange event to fire.

```
$numitems = $ie.Document.getElementById('DisplayCount')
$numitems.value = "1000"
$numitems.FireEvent("onchange")
While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 3;}
```

I am a frequent consumer of help from the internet, but this is my first time sharing, I hope it helps.